# Get Command used to run Process

Tags: c#, command-line

In a C program in Linux, I can use the first argument to get the command that was used to run a process. Is there a way to do something similar for C#?

For example, if I use `dotnet run`/`dotnet` to run the program or double-click a published executable, is it possible to retrieve that programmatically (`dotnet run`, `dotnet <…>.dll`, or `<executable path>`)?

I can get the DLL/EXE that is running with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, but that doesn't help much when the user is running the project directly with `dotnet run` instead of `dotnet <…>.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Environment.CommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline) property to get the command line for the current program. Note that in the case of `dotnet run myassembly.exe`, the `dotnet run` part is dropped. E.g. if the command line is `dotnet run myassbembly.exe foo bar`, the `Environment.CommandLine` property will contain `myassembly.exe foo bar`.

Comment: Looks like it's just adding the `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to the `args` data. No real way to get the `dotnet run` part then?